# Error for convergence for Runge-Kutta in Python

Tags: python, runge-kutta, convergence

I have this piece of code (I put just a part of it) in Python:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
from numpy import linalg as LA

a = [[5/36,2/9-sqrt(15)/15,5/36-sqrt(15)/30],[5/36+sqrt(15)/24,2/9,5/36-sqrt(15)/24],[5/36+sqrt(15)/30,2/9+sqrt(15)/15,5/36]]


treshold = 10**(-12)
h = 0.01

def sho(x, t=None):
    k = 1.
    t = float(t)
    x = array(x)
    return array([  x[1],
              - x[0]])


def iterate_Z(func,Z,y,h,t):
    crit = 1
    Z = transpose(Z)
    while crit > treshold:
        T = []
        for i in range(len(Z)):
            sum = 0
            for j in range(len(Z)):
                sum = sum + a[i][j]*f(y[-1]+Z[j],t[-1])
            T = T + [h*sum]
        crit = norm(Z-T)
        Z = np.array(T)
    return(Z)

iterate_Z(sho,[[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],[[1,2],[2,3]],0.01,[0,1])
```

So what I am doing is to solve the simple harmonic oscillator using a symplectic Runge-Kutta. (The formulas I use are from a book and I checked I copied them correctly). So in iterate_Z I pick some initial values for Z and I do some iterations, in order to get a much better value, from which to go to the next step of Runge-Kutta. When I run the program (and add a print inside the function), it gives output for a few steps and after that I get this error:

```
File "mtrand.pyx", line 2093, in mtrand.RandomState.f (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:23649)ValueError: dfnum <= 0
```

pointing to this line:

```
sum = sum + a[i][j]*f(y[-1]+Z[j],t[-1])
```

Can someone tell me what this error means and how can I fix it? Thank you!

Comment: There's some error related to the random number generator, which is a little odd, since your code doesn't use any random numbers...

Comment: On that line, what is the function f() doing?  I can't see it defined anywhere.

Comment: @Turksarama that was supposed to be func... Feeling so stupid.. Thank you so much!